# Can I go back to default controller from custom auth controller in strapi?

Tags: node.js, strapi

This is my overriding method. in extensions/user-permissions/controllers/Auth.js

```
register:() => {
//do something here and call default register from Controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Either:

- remove (or comment out) the customized function (in this case `register`)
- remove the file that contains the customized functionalities (in this case `Auth.js`) *(note that if you've customized any other functions other than `register` they will be set back to default as well).*